# API doesn't seem to run on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, android, ios, angularjs, jquery-mobile

I'm currently trying debug an API issue that I can't seem to get it running on a mobile browser (iOS or Android). The API i'm using is Bitly API that shortens URL. So far I've managed to get working on desktop browser (Chrome, Mozilla, Safari). But if I tried checking it on a mobile browser it doesn't seem to be running. There wasn't any errors on the console.

Currently using Angular 1 for my Web App. Here you can see below this is a API placed inside the controller. I'm using `$timeout` to run the API once the page/view finishes loading.

### **UPDATE**

So I tried moving the API outside the `$timeout(function())`, and the output is still the same. It shows a result on the desktop but on the mobile browser no result

```
    var base_url      = window.location.origin,
        hash_bang     = "/#/sign-up?referral=",
        login         = "login",
        api_key       = "api_key",
        ref_code = document.getElementById('input-refcode').value;

        function get_short_url(login, api_key, func) {
            $.getJSON(
                "https://api-ssl.bitly.com//v3/shorten?callback=?", 
                { 
                    "format": "json",
                    "apiKey": api_key,
                    "login": login,
                    "longUrl": base_url + hash_bang + ref_code
                },

                function(response)
                {
                    func(response.data.url);
                }
            );
        }

    get_short_url(login, api_key, function(short_url) {

        $('#input-refcode').val(short_url);
        $('.url-code').val(short_url);
        alert(short_url);
    });






    <div class="invite-code" ng-init="code()">

        <input class="input url-code" disabled=true id="input-urlcode" />

        <input class="input referral-code" disabled="true" ng-model="account.referral_code_string" id="input-refcode" />

        <button class="copy-code-btn">Copy URL</button>
    </div>
```

---

```
var ctrls = angular.module('elstudio.controllers.site');

ctrls.controller('FreeRidesCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $timeout, $window, UserService, AuthService,
                                          UserPackageService, ReferralService) {

    // $timeout(function() {
    //   alert('test');
    // })

    $timeout(function(){
        var base_url      = window.location.origin,
            hash_bang     = "/#/sign-up?referral=",
            login         = "login",
            api_key       = "api_key",
            ref_code = document.getElementById('input-refcode').value;

            function get_short_url(login, api_key, func) {
                $.getJSON(
                    "https://api-ssl.bitly.com//v3/shorten?callback=?", 
                    { 
                        "format": "json",
                        "apiKey": api_key,
                        "login": login,
                        "longUrl": base_url + hash_bang + ref_code
                    },

                    function(response)
                    {
                        func(response.data.url);
                    }
                );
            }

        get_short_url(login, api_key, function(short_url) {

            $('#input-refcode').val(short_url);
            $('.url-code').val(short_url);
            alert(short_url);
        });

    }); //note, no time parameter



  }
});
```

Here is a screenshot of the output in desktop. As you can see the bitly API is present shown in a red stroke

[image]

But if I tried checking it on a mobile browser. Bitly output is missing on the textbox
[image]

I even tried using `alert`. On desktop it prompts the javascript `alert`, but on mobile it doesn't trigger the `alert`

Comment: Could please also check the network, weather the request reached server and you got the appropriate response from server. If it is as expected then you can confirm the problem is through injecting the value into text field. You can try that separately. Hope this information help full

Comment: @AnkireddyPolu just checked the network and I got the correct response.

Comment: So it means  get_short_url function not even invoked when you got the response.  Add alert while invoking function. One more suggestion try with different names to the function